# Opening hyperlink in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice

1. I am inserting a hyperlink into OpenOffice Writer on a highlighted word - 'the_hyperlink'.
2. I am choosing 'Insert' from the task bar and 'Hyperlink' from the dropdown list.
3. I paste the link into 'Target' and the highlighted 'the_hyperlink' is already in the Text field.
4. Click Apply.

The hyperlink box doesn't automatically disappear (as in, task done) but if I click out of it it has created a hyperlink.

My Problem is it does not open the hyperlink if you left click on it. It only does so if you right click and select 'Open Hyperlink'. I need it to do the former.

Answer (score 5):

In both LibreOffice and OpenOffice, there's a security option "`Ctrl-click required to follow hyperlinks`". If this option is enabled (AFAIK it's enabled by default), a single left click isn't sufficient to open the hyperlink:

You can open the option dialogue using menu "`Tools`" -> "`Options`" -> "`LibreOffice`" -> "`Security`" -> "`Security options and Warnings`" -> <kbd>Options...</kbd> button:

[image]

Check if the option "`Ctrl-click required to follow hyperlinks`" is set, and disable it if you prefer to:

[image]

Besides, if you move the mouse pointer over the hyperlink, a tooltip should appear telling you if a single click or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click is required to open the link:

- "`Ctrl-click required...`" **enabled**:

  [image]
- "`Ctrl-click required...`" **disabled**:

  [image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought it would be fairly easy to fix but these things are not always obvious. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @tohuwawohu What is the way to open the link (security is disabled) without the mouse? Are we forced to make usage of the mouse to open a hyperlink?

Comment: @RudyVissers: At least in LO Writer, you can use the context menu to open the hyperlink. Modern keyboards should have a certain key to open the context menu; the context menu should contain two link-related entries, "Edit Hyperlink" and "Open Hyperlink".